# Quartz.net CRON expression always returns last day of month?

Tags: quartz.net, cronexpression

I'm a quartz newbie.

I'm simply attempting to find out if Quartz.net can, given a start date (possibly in the past), an end date and an interval calculate the correct date occurances - it might not be Quartz's primary use case but it appears possible from what i can discover of the API.

So given this fragment:

var exp = new CronExpression("0 0 0 1/7 * ? *");

```
    var next = exp.GetNextValidTimeAfter(new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 12, 30, 00).ToUniversalTime());
    while (next < DateTime.Parse("30 Oct 2012"))
    {
        next = exp.GetNextValidTimeAfter(next.Value);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(next);
    }
```

The results appear to be (truncated):

14/01/2012 11:00:00 a.m. +00:00

21/01/2012 11:00:00 a.m. +00:00

28/01/2012 11:00:00 a.m. +00:00

***31/01/2012 11:00:00 a.m. +00:00***

7/02/2012 11:00:00 a.m. +00:00

14/02/2012 11:00:00 a.m. +00:00

21/02/2012 11:00:00 a.m. +00:00

28/02/2012 11:00:00 a.m. +00:00

***29/02/2012 11:00:00 a.m. +00:00***

7/03/2012 11:00:00 a.m. +00:00

Errr... It seems Quartz's CRON expression always includes the last day of month and essentially calculates the next date from there? Or is my expectation / understanding of quartz / cron wrong?

Also these results seem to be backed up using http://www.cronmaker.com/...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can't achieve what you're looking for with a cron expression.

If you download and use [Quartz.Net 2.x](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet) you can use a new type of trigger called [CalendarIntervalTrigger](http://jvilalta.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/new-in-quartznet-20the-calendar.html) which can be used to manage different interval units.

I've tested this bit of code and it works the way you expect:

```
DateTimeOffset startCalendar = DateBuilder.DateOf(11, 0, 0, 14, 1, 2012);

var weeklyTrigger = new CalendarIntervalTriggerImpl
{
    StartTimeUtc = startCalendar,
    RepeatIntervalUnit = IntervalUnit.Week,
    RepeatInterval = 1  // every one week;
};

IList<DateTimeOffset> fireTimes = TriggerUtils.ComputeFireTimes(weeklyTrigger, null, 10);

foreach (var item in fireTimes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Result:

> 14/01/2012 11:00:00 +00:00
>   21/01/2012 11:00:00 +00:00
>   28/01/2012 11:00:00 +00:00
>   04/02/2012 11:00:00 +00:00
>   11/02/2012 11:00:00 +00:00
>   18/02/2012 11:00:00 +00:00
>   25/02/2012 11:00:00 +00:00
>   03/03/2012 11:00:00 +00:00
>   10/03/2012 11:00:00 +00:00
>   17/03/2012 11:00:00 +00:00

Comment: Appreciate the effort attempting answering this question - not sure whether i should mark it currently as the answer since the actual question isn't how would we achieve the correct outcome but whether CRON works the way we observed or whether it was Quartz's implementation?

Comment: Sorry to LeftyX above but my best answer (very recently discovered) appears to be tied up with the general behavior of CRON - it appears that each unit is "boxed" for want of a better term in that for a given unit e.g. days in this case you cannot overflow into the next unit (months). A poorly but hopefully enough to explain what we're seeing with several cron test tools?

Comment: @6footunder: what you're trying to do is not possible with a single CRON expression (not even in Unix) http://superuser.com/questions/110911/how-can-i-create-a-cron-job-that-runs-a-task-every-three-weeks The only possibile solution is to create multiple cron expression or use the above solution.

Comment: Fair enough - the link was helpful